# ADO - how to get primary key fields

Tags: database, delphi, ado, c++builder, vcl

I'm using ADO (Delphi & C++ Builder) and I would like get primary key fields (their names) that are in some TADOTable component. How to do it?

I found out that I need to use ADOConnection->OpenSchema but don't know how to use this..

Now I tried this:

```
int bounds[] = {0,2};
OleVariant A(bounds,1, varVariant);
A.PutElement(varEmpty,0);
A.PutElement(varEmpty,1);
A.PutElement("MyDBTable",2);


OleVariant EmptyParam;
EmptyParam.VType = VT_ERROR;
EmptyParam.VError = DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND;
TADODataSet *temp = new TADODataSet(NULL);

AdoConnection1->OpenSchema(siPrimaryKeys, A, EmptyParam, temp);
temp->Open();
temp->First();
while (!temp->Eof)
{
    Memo1->Lines->Add(temp->Fields->Fields[0]->AsString);
    temp->Next();
}
temp->Close();
delete temp;
```

When running this code I get: "Object or provider is not capable of performing requested operation."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

References for [OpenSchema Method (ADO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee275721%28v=bts.10%29.aspx), examples can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186246)

An example implemention in Delphi for  Microsoft Access and MSSqlServer could look like this:

```
Procedure OpenPrimaryKeyInfo ( Connection:TAdoConnection
                             ; DatabaseName , SchemaName , TableName : Variant
                             ; Display:TAdodataset );
begin
  Connection.OpenSchema( siPrimaryKeys
                        , VarArrayOf([ DatabaseName , SchemaName , TableName ])
                        , EmptyParam , Display );
end;
```

Example call for Microsoft Access:

```
OpenPrimaryKeyInfo( AdoConnection2 , UnAssigned , UnAssigned , 'TableX' , Adodataset1 );
```

Example call for MSSqlServer:

```
OpenPrimaryKeyInfo( AdoConnection1 , 'MyDataBase' , 'dbo' , 'TableX' , Adodataset1 );
```

Comment: This looks great. It's just.. how to write VarArrayOf([ DatabaseName , SchemaName , TableName ]) in C++ Builder?

Comment: @Tracer: The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Variants.VarArrayOf) shows you the C++ Builder syntax (there's a link to a C++ code example at the bottom of that page as well).

Answer (score 3):

You establish the connection and open it as usual (using `TADOConnection.ConnectionString` and `TADOConnection.Open`), and then ask for the schema using `OpenSchema`. The `TADODataSet` you provide as the last parameter will contain a `RecordSet` that you can use just like any other dataset.

Here's a quick sample I threw together (thanks to @bummi for the correction to the third parameter - `Unassigned` and `Null` both compiled, but didn't actually work when tested). I dropped a `TADOConnection`, `TADODataSet`, and `TMemo` on a new form and configured the `TADOConnection` quickly to point to a simple SQL Server Express database I have for some testing - I included the connection string; the only change I made to it was in the computer name provided in the `Data Source` portion).

```
procedure TForm3.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  sLine: string;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  ADOConnection1.ConnectionString := 'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;' +
                                     'Integrated Security=SSPI;' + 
                                     'Persist Security Info=False;' +
                                     'Initial Catalog=Contacts;' +
                                     'Data Source=MyComputer\SQLEXPRESS';
  ADOConnection1.Connected := True;
  ADOConnection1.OpenSchema(siPrimaryKeys, Unassigned, EmptyParam, ADODataSet1);
  sLine := '';
  for i := 0 to ADODataSet1.FieldCount - 1 do
    sLine := sLine + ADODataSet1.Fields[i].FieldName + #9;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(sLine);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('');

  while not ADODataSet1.Eof do
  begin
    sLine := '';
    for i := 0 to ADODataSet1.FieldCount - 1 do
      sLine := sLine + ADODataSet1.Fields[i].AsString + #9;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(sLine);
    ADODataSet1.Next;
  end;
end;
```

The possible values for the `SchemaInfo` value (the first parameter passed to `OpenSchema`) can be found in the `ADODB` unit - they're documented in the [Delphi help file](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TSchemaInfo) (note that the documentation says that not all of them are available via ADO):

```
TSchemaInfo = (siAsserts, siCatalogs, siCharacterSets, siCollations,
  siColumns, siCheckConstraints, siConstraintColumnUsage,
  siConstraintTableUsage, siKeyColumnUsage, siReferentialConstraints,
  siTableConstraints, siColumnsDomainUsage, siIndexes, siColumnPrivileges,
  siTablePrivileges, siUsagePrivileges, siProcedures, siSchemata,
  siSQLLanguages, siStatistics, siTables, siTranslations, siProviderTypes,
  siViews, siViewColumnUsage, siViewTableUsage, siProcedureParameters,
  siForeignKeys, siPrimaryKeys, siProcedureColumns, siDBInfoKeywords,
  siDBInfoLiterals, siCubes, siDimensions, siHierarchies, siLevels,
  siMeasures, siProperties, siMembers, siProviderSpecific);
```

Comment: Does not the second Unassigned need to be EmptyParam, I can't get it working with Unassigned.

Comment: @bummi: Yep, you're absolutely correct. It compiled with both `Null` and `Unassigned`, but failed when actually running the code. I've corrected it (with appropriate credit given to you for spotting it), and included actual working test code. Thanks for the catch. (I had already upvoted your answer, BTW.) :-)